# Is this sentence from Marrascaud a reference to another novel or movie?

Tags: poirot

In the movie Hercule's works, Poirot is finding who is Marrascaud the thief and killer. In one of the last scenes, when Marrascaud is taken by the police, Marrascaud turns and says to Poirot:

> We will meet again

To what Poirot answers:

> I will not turn back

So the question is: why does Marrascaud say that? I would suppose this is a reference to another movie or novel where Marrascaud is there, but I could not find such a plot.

Comment: It means he thinks they will meet again. Why would it be a reference?

Comment: There must be *thousands and thousands* of stories in which the villain swears "We'll meet again!" as they're taken away. Is there any reason to suspect that it's being said as a reference to one of those, rather than just as a stock phrase?

Comment: Do you mean the (feature-length) episode ‘[_The Labours Of Hercules_](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2119593/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1)’ from the TV series [_Agatha Christie's Poirot_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agatha_Christie%27s_Poirot) with David Suchet? (If so, note that the book — a linked series of 13 short stories — was heavily changed in the adaptation, with only elements of many of the stories surviving. In particular, the identify of Marrascaud is different from the book.)

Comment: I meant the TV show yes which regroups multiple plots from the series of novel "The Labour of Hercule" into one movie
@F1Krazy Because in Agatha Christie, usually, this is not a "super hero" type of story: once a bad guy 's identity is discovered, this is over for him and he will never show up again. So the "we'll meet again" and Poirot answering nearly positively (instead of: "nope, you'll be hanged for your crime") is weird
That's why I supposed it was a reference, but I might be wrong of course

Comment: I guess there is a possibility it is a reference to Sherlock Holmes and Professor Moriarity. specificlly to the play Sherlock Holmes (1899), which is not in canon with the short stories and novels.  I think I remember that when captured Moriarity says he will meet Holmes again,  possibly as the Reichenbach Falls, but Holmes doesn't care abotu those threats. 
So possibly it is a threat by Masrascaud to kill Pirot sometime in the future, and Pirot's reply thathe won't let fear of Marrascaud deter him from investigating crimes in the future.